# .net MAUI not able to debug on physicle iPhone

Tags: ios, maui

I've been following this blog for getting started with MAUI on macOS.

https://dev.to/davidortinau/installing-net-maui-on-macos-4mmc

I have everything set up as instructed but the tutorial only show how to start your project on the ios simulator.

I tried plugging my iPhone UUID into this command below but it gives me an error saying that it couldnt find the simulator. I dont want it to run on simulator. I need to find a way to start the app in the physical iPhone.

`dotnet build -t:Run -f net6.0-ios -p:_DeviceName=:v2:udid=02C556DA-64B8-440B-8F06-F8C56BB7CC22`

I'm on version 6.0.102

Has anyone been having the same issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use a physical device, don't use the `:v2:udid=` prefix. So the command simply becomes: `dotnet build -t:Run -f net6.0-ios -p:_DeviceName=02C556DA-64B8-440B-8F06-F8C56BB7CC22`

Comment: Thank you! That was so simple and yet i must have missed it in the documentation somewhere.
Love your youtube channel btw :) I've been watching your videos to get up to speed on MAUI

Comment: Haha it isn't super obvious tbh. This will of course be easier in the future when the tooling catches up. Thanks for the kind words <3

Comment: I get failed to create simulator with that

Comment: @GeraldVersluis This no longer works on physical device. Could you update your answer? In the dotnet build command line reference there is nothing about a -t command line. I get MT1207: Could not fined the simulator device type when I'm giving the identifier for an iPad.